# what is the name of this part (bar or ribbon) of window in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

[Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFqJW.png)

Hi!
What is the name of that part I have shown in a picture in the android studio?
and how can I hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's breadcrumbs. You could disable them in "Settings | Editor | General | Appearance - Show breadcrumbs"